# Can we define a C++ method in a C file?

Tags: c++

Assume that we have a C++ project. We can use a function which defined in a C file in the C++ project through `extern "C"` keyword. Example:

**C code**:  cfile.c

```
#include <stdio.h>

void f(void)
{
    printf("\n This is a C code\n");
}
```

**Cpp Code**: cppfile.cpp

```
#include <iostream>

extern "C" {
void f();
}

int main(void)
{
    f();
    return 0;
}
```

So, can we do that for the opposite case:

**Cpp code**: cppCode.cpp

```
struct MyClass
{
    virtual void f(const char* text);
    void func(const char* text);
};
```

Can we implement `f` method and `func` method in a C file (for instance: **cCode.c**) **???** Is that possible ? (*Just the question for my personal purpose*)

Comment: No. Class member functions always have C++ language linkage, so they can never match any function exported by a C translation unit.

Comment: @KerrekSB Can't you edit that in options?

Comment: @GillBates, no, it is not possible, since the calling  convention is different. C compiler can't generate proper call to class method.

Comment: You cannot use C++ class in C code directly. But you can use COM for such purpose.

Comment: How would the C compiler compile the method?  C++ compilers can understand (most of) C because that has been a design goal from the beginning; but there's no reason to expect C compilers to understand C++.

Answer (score 4):

You can't do this directly. However, there is a workaround (of sorts). You can have a function with "C" linkage which returns the pointer to the object of the class - presumably dynamically allocated - converted to `void*`.

Than you can implement functions which would map to functions inside the class, but would take one additional argument - `void*`, which would be the address obtained from the call to creation function above. They would simply convert this  `void*` to the type of the class and call it's member.

In the end, you'd need a dispose function which would corectly delete the pointer.

Comment: if possible, could you give me a detailed example SergeyA. Thanks